# How to create hot spots on an image with mouse over and clickable area?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, sql, vb.net

I have a scenario where i want to create hot spot on image.I want to let the hot spots on image be created by the user.Suppose user want to create rectangle on image then he just need to left click with mouse and create rectangle and this rectangle should be displayed with clickable area(Hot spot.).I need it because I need to create a page where a user can select specific area and should be the clickable in future.Can any one please suggest me the way.

here is the example image.I am now able to draw lines on image but i want to create rectangle which should be clickable with mouse over.
[image]

the background is an image and blue thin line is drawn by mouse.

Comment: Can you provide a picture or diagram as an example? Whathaveyoutried?

Comment: First of all thank you for reading my question Sir.
I just added an image above.Please see this and reply me soon.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to wrap your image into a `relative` positioned `DIV`. Then add `mousedown` event listener for the image. In this handler store the click- coordinates and add `mouseup` listener for the image. In this `mouseUp()` store the mouseup-coordinates, remove all previous handlers and create a new `DIV` to the document. Then add `click` and `mouseover` event listeners for the new `DIV`, style the position `absolute`, actual position and size you can calculate from stored coordinates. Finally append newly created `DIV` to the image wrapper.

Instead of using a `DIV` as a hotspot , you can include an empty `MAP` element in your document, and then create new `AREA`(s) to this `MAP`.

**EDIT**

I'm really not sure what you need, but...

Creating a `DIV` in `mouseUpHandler()`:

```
var clickableDiv = imgWrapper.appendChild(document.createElement('DIV'));
clickableDiv.style.position = 'absolute';
clickableDiv.style.top = calculatedY;
clickableDiv.style.left = calculatedX;
clickableDiv.style.width = calculatedWidth;
clickableDiv.style.height = calculatedHeight;
clickableDiv.style.backGround = '#fff';
clickableDiv.style.opacity = '0.5';
clickableDiv.addEventListener('click', doSomethingOnClick, false);
```

You're free to style the `clickableDiv` as you wish, but `backGround` and `opacity` (can be also 0) are needed to make the `DIV` clickable. `doSomethingOnClick` is a function name, which handles clicks on the `clickableDiv`.

Comment: Thank you for reading my question.Nice reply by you.This is good but I have a question that how can I handle mouse events in Div instead of using Image control.

Comment: I've built my answer on JS/HTML. I think this more like a C# question, which unfortenately is beyond my knowledge :(.

Comment: No worries.I'll be thankful.Please let me know the link which you have built.Its urgent Sir.(JS/HTML would be work.)

Comment: Well thank you so m uch again.This is working nice when i fixed position in JScript function.But when I'm trying to do this dynamically it seem error on page.Actually my problem is that I want to add a Div on image when user Clicks on the particular place on the image.I need it because I have an image of Construction site and I want to create a page where the user let spot allotted area on image.So this area can be seen as allotted for  the particular person.

Comment: Hmm... `IMG` is a void element. It can't have any kind of a content. That's why my first advice was to wrap the image into a `DIV`. Have you visited at https://developer.mozilla.org/ ? There you can find details of JS/HTML.

Comment: I tried this previously but there was problem handling mouse event within DIV.I wrapped image in div and now the question is how can i Handle mouse event over the div.......I get hanged :(

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing the code you've created. Add the codesnippet into your question, or perhaps ask a new question about event handling.